Missing commit information on new code in Sonarqube
I installed sonarqube locally on windows (community Edition Version 9.9.3, build 79811) with scanner version 6.2.1.
I cloned repo from bitbucket, and edited the sonar-scanner and sonar-properties files with:
“sonar.scm.provider=.git”
“sonar.scm.disabled=true”

Afterward I pushed commit with vulnerability so the next scan will catch it.
I was expecting to see in the soar GUI the vulnerability with all the commit information like date, commit id and contributor, however, the only information I could see I was the commit date. any idea what is missing in order to see also the commit id and contributor? it’s mandatory as part of request I got from product, but I couldn’t find any web information for this issue.
One more note: my user did the commit, and I already logged in with that user to sonar and I gave it admin and analysis permissions
